# Data table aggregate by week and userid

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using R and have a data table `DT` with 30 million rows:

```
userid,     date, measurement
   101, 1/1/2011,          13
   101, 2/1/2011,          42
   ...
   333, 1/1/2011,          67
   ...
```

I'm thinking of aggregating the observations by userid and ***week***.

My current idea is to convert date into an integer, and then divide by 7 and use the floor function, creating a new variable week. Finally, I can use the

```
DT[,.(measurement.Sum = sum(measurement)),by=.(userid,week)]
```

Would this be the fastest way of doing things? (I read about the zoo library but it seems troublesome to switch between data.table and zoo library)

Comment: @ulfelder The OP seems to be using data.table, which already includes a `week` function... I'm not clear on why they might need another here...?

Comment: I didn't know that data table contains week! thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.table has a `week` function:

See, for example, [How to get week numbers from dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439540/how-to-get-week-numbers-from-dates)