# Set another first day of the week in R

Tags: r

I have a list of 3680 dates (YYYY-MM-DD) and I need to create a function that gives me the week number for each date. However, my week starts on wednesday and not sunday, as it's set by default on R.

Any idea on how to do that? I tried with lubridate and with as.week, but couldnt get there with none of these functions.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439540/how-to-get-week-numbers-from-dates

Comment: thanks, but I tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43866536/8918706
but it always returns 0..

Comment: It looks like it's `lubridate` option `getOption("lubridate.week.start", 3)`: http://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/day.html