# Formatting DateTime to week number

Tags: datetime, julia, date-formatting

I'm trying to format a `DateTime` object to a `String` by using the `Dates.format()` function.
I'd like to get the week number for a specific time, however I can't find right [formatting option in the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/#Dates.format).

I know I could get this by running `Dates.week` but I would really like to know if it's possible via `format` to have cleaner code (and crack a code golfing challenge...).

Here's some actual code:

```
julia> my_time = now()
2018-03-22T08:16:15.601

julia> Dates.week(my_time)
12

julia> Dates.format(my_time, "Y m d H:M:S")
"2018 3 22 8:16:15"
```

In R, I could do "%V" to [get the weeks formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439540/how-to-get-week-numbers-from-dates). Is there a similar way in Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a format specifier like %V:

```
julia> Base.Dates.CONVERSION_SPECIFIERS
Dict{Char,Type} with 12 entries:
  'm' => Base.Dates.Month
  'd' => Base.Dates.Day
  'M' => Base.Dates.Minute
  'Y' => Base.Dates.Year
  'e' => Base.Dates.DayOfWeekToken
  's' => Base.Dates.Millisecond
  'U' => Base.Dates.Month
  'E' => Base.Dates.DayOfWeekToken
  'H' => Base.Dates.Hour
  'y' => Base.Dates.Year
  'u' => Base.Dates.Month
  'S' => Base.Dates.Second
```

The in the code for these specifiers there's [a note](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/274f0a2e9948b2900ea6b78e71fba7d9fccc8ff7/stdlib/Dates/src/io.jl#L249) that there should be a way for packages to add more.

Comment: Thanks for showing this. Very useful! I wish it had all the other similar dates functions.