# weekofyear() returning seemingly incorrect results for January 1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, week-number

I'm not quite sure why my code gives 52 as the answer for: `weekofyear("01/JAN/2017")` .

Does anyone have a possible explanation for this? Is there a better way to do this?

```python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('weekOfYear').getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "01/JAN/2017"), (2, "15/FEB/2017")], ("id", "date")) 

df.show()
+---+-----------+
| id|       date|
+---+-----------+
|  1|01/JAN/2017|
|  2|15/FEB/2017|
+---+-----------+
```

Calculate the week of the year

```python
df=df.withColumn("weekofyear", functions.weekofyear(to_date(df["date"],"dd/MMM/yyyy")))

df.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- weekofyear: integer (nullable = true)

df.show()
```

The 'error' is visible below:

```
+---+-----------+----------+
| id|       date|weekofyear|
+---+-----------+----------+
|  1|01/JAN/2017|        52|
|  2|15/FEB/2017|         7|
+---+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like `weekofyear()` will only return 1 for January 1st if the day of the week is Monday through Thursday.

To confirm, I created a DataFrame with all `"01/JAN/YYYY"` from 1900 to 2018:

```python
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "01/JAN/{y}".format(y=year),) for year in range(1900,2019)],
    ["id", "date"]
)
```

Now let's convert it to a date, get the day of the week, and count the values for `weekofyear()`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.withColumn("d", f.to_date(f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp('date', "dd/MMM/yyyy"))))\
    .withColumn("weekofyear", f.weekofyear("d"))\
    .withColumn("dayofweek", f.date_format("d", "E"))\
    .groupBy("dayofweek", "weekofyear")\
    .count()\
    .show()
#+---------+----------+-----+
#|dayofweek|weekofyear|count|
#+---------+----------+-----+
#|      Sun|        52|   17|
#|      Mon|         1|   18|
#|      Tue|         1|   17|
#|      Wed|         1|   17|
#|      Thu|         1|   17|
#|      Fri|        53|   17|
#|      Sat|        53|    4|
#|      Sat|        52|   12|
#+---------+----------+-----+
```

Note, I am using Spark v 2.1 where [`to_date()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) does not accept a format argument, so I had to use the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273036/5858851) to convert the string to a date.

Similarly `to_date()` only returns 1 for:

- January 2nd, if the day of the week is Monday through Friday.
- January 3rd, if the day of the week is Monday through Saturday.

---

**Update**

This behavior is consistent with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) definition.

Comment: many thanks - looks like there may be some room to improve on  the weekofyear() function in the 'to_date' library ....

Comment: @gps actually this seems like it's the ISO standard according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering)

Comment: according to your link it looks like the day (Mon,Tues,....)  of the 1st day of the first week of the year plays a major  role in deciding whether or not this 'first day' falls part of the last week of the old year or the first week of the new year ....

Comment: Indeed this works like stated in ISO 8601 but then the function year does not so if I want to concat the year and the week # it gets all mess up because year will always get the year in the date and will not be in accordance to weekofyear, which for JAN 1 might return a value of the past year. Is there a specific function to deal with this or do I need my own logic?

Comment: Is there a way to get the 'year' that corresponds to this 'weekofyear'? E.g., if the month is Jan, and the WoY is 53, then I would think there should be a way to easily access the prior calendar year.

Comment: You can do it with a `when` - something like `when((month("mydatecol")==1) &(weekofyear("mydatecol") ==53),year("mydatecol")-1). otherwise (..)`

Comment: Agree, Spark should return a response in the format YYYY-Wk. Or there needs to be an ISO_8601_year() function.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to take the ceiling of the `(day of the year / 7)`, which probably fits with how most people think about the week of the year:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2023-01-01',),('2023-01-07',),('2023-01-08',)], ['date'])

df.withColumn(
    'week', F.ceil(F.dayofyear('date') / 7)
).show()

+----------+----+
|      date|week|
+----------+----+
|2023-01-01|   1|
|2023-01-07|   1|
|2023-01-08|   2|
+----------+----+
```

For the sake of comparison, here is the behavior of `F.weekofyear`:

```
df.withColumn(
    'weekofyear', F.weekofyear('date')
).show()

+----------+----------+
|      date|weekofyear|
+----------+----------+
|2023-01-01|        52|
|2023-01-07|         1|
|2023-01-08|         1|
+----------+----------+
```