# How to get week of year from dateTime object in python?

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, week-number

So given a `datetime` object, I want to get week of year from it with `CalendarWeekRule` is `FirstDay` and `DayOfWeek` is Monday.

In C# i can achieve this with:

```
int week = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

And in python I have tried to achieve it with:

```
myDate.isocalendar()[1]
```

And

```
myDate.strftime("%V")
```

But I am unable to get correct week no for some dates like for:

1) `2015-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000`

- C# UsageWeek: `01`
- Python UsageWeek: `01`

So it is right.

but for:

2) `2016-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000`

- C# UsageWeek: `01`
- Python UsageWeek: `53`

This is wrong.

Comment: @Barmar. People use to declare questions as duplicate even if previous question do not answer the the question or requirements.

Comment: There are multiple ways to define when the first week of the year starts, and different date libraries choose different methods.

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks for replying, I have used these:
myDate.isocalendar()[1]
myDate.strftime("%V")
myDate.strftime("%U")
myDate.strftime("%W")
But I was not able to get what I want... I want to achieve what C# is giving.

Comment: It looks like Python doesn't have a method that uses the `FirstDay` rule. It just has a choice between Sunday and Monday as the beginning of the week.

Comment: Here's an answer that shows how to do it where week 1 is always Jan 1-7: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2608868/1491895. It's closer to what you want.

Comment: @Barmar, have already gone through it. Not gives correct answer that is given by C#.

Comment: I know, that's why I said it's closer to what you want, not exactly the same.

Comment: Isn't it lucky that Python allows you to write your own functions, you're not limited to built-in functions?

Comment: yup, lucky with no luck till now. :)

Comment: Get the ISO week number, and get the day of week of Jan 1 that year. If the DOW is Fri-Sun, subtract 1 from the week number to get the week number you want.

Comment: Why is this tagged pyspark? Pyspark [`weekofyear`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.weekofyear) will return the week of the [year based on the ISO 8601 definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904570/weekofyear-returning-seemingly-incorrect-results-for-january-1).

Comment: @pault. So I have a timestampType column in pyspark dataframe, I used this built-in spark function "weekofyear" to get week but it does not return what i want. I want to replicate C# functionality where CalendarWeekRule is "FirstDay" and DayOfWeek is "Monday". So I thought of achieving it through custom functionality by writing UDF. But currently now no luck.