# Calculating week number of year (dealing with first week of year)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert the date into week number of year.

In my case, *I cannot include the day of one year into another year.*

The `isocalendar()` works fine to find week number, however, it assumes some rules: **if the first week in January has less than 4 days, it is counted as the last week of the year before.**

So, this function returns:

```
date(2016, 1, 1).isocalendar()[1]
53
```

Is there some way, using this function, to change this, to **return week 0** instead of week 53 (from previous year) ?

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439540/how-to-get-week-numbers-from-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this?

```
import datetime
datetime.date(2016, 1, 1).strftime("%U")
```